# Python Multiprocessing Data Exchange

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

I am trying to pass data between 2 threads within the same process, the main thread spawns a new thread in a separate class.  I attempted to pass a string utilizing the `multiprocessing.Queue` object.

I don't understand why the 2nd thread does not see the data in the queue.

mainClass.py

```
if(__name__ == '__main__'):
    # Create the threads
    itemInterestThread = NewItemInterestHelper("Item Interest Thread")

    # Start the Item Interest Thread
    itemInterestThread.run()

    time.sleep(1)
    print "Adding item\n"
    itemInterestThread.addToQueue("Neat Thing")
    time.sleep(1)
    print "Adding item\n"
    itemInterestThread.addToQueue("Neat Thing2")

    print "Sleeping for 5 seconds"
    time.sleep(5)
```

NewItemInterestHelper.py

```
import multiprocessing
import time

class NewItemInterestHelper:
    # Class Variables
    __itemsQueue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    __itemMutex = multiprocessing.Lock()
    __pool = multiprocessing.Process()

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def run(self):
        self.__pool = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.dowork)
        self.__pool.start()

    def dowork(self):
        while True:
            self.__itemMutex.acquire()
            if not self.__itemsQueue.empty():
                print "Got " + self.__itemsQueue.get() + "\n"

            self.__itemMutex.release()
            time.sleep(1)

    def addToQueue(self, queueAddition):
        self.__itemMutex.acquire()
        self.__itemsQueue.put(queueAddition)
        self.__itemMutex.release()
```

Comment: Are you indeed trying to use two threads within the same process? Because your code (and my answer below) uses two separate processes. If you really want to use threads in the same process, you should usie the `threading`module, rather than `multiprocessing`. Note, though, that threads in Python are not a good fit for CPU bound tasks, due to the infamous GIL (global interpreter lock) in Python. They work fine, however, for handling IO bound tasks.

Comment: My goal is to have a single "application" that can pass data between threads in such a way that I can perform 2 tasks "simultaneously" (depending on the CPU) like I would be able to in c++

Comment: So, you do want `multiprocessing` just as you are using. However, this is different from threads. And in Python specifically, due to the global interpreter lock, threads cannot (normally) be used to run different tasks simultaneously, as long as not (at least) one of the tasks is to wait for IO. So, the answer I gave is still OK but you need to read up on the difference between threads and multiprocessing in Python.

Comment: Thank you very much. That clears things up a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are confusing threading and multiprocessing in your question. They are not the same thing. It would probably be good if you update your question to be clearer. Threading is done in the same process (conceptually at least) and will therefore share all global variables and states. When doing multiprocessing, the processes will be independent of each other and will therefore **not** share the global variables and states. Instead, each process will instantiate their own.

Because of this, your class variables (which in effect are global variables) will not be shared between your main and your auxiliary process. The different processes will have their own queues and locks, created from scratch.

However, if the lock and queue instead belong to the object, rather than the class, they will be copied when the auxiliary process is spawned. That way they will share enough of their internals to do what you want them to do. Thus if you change your `NewItemInterestHelper` to make the lock and the queue being part of the dynamic object instead, it should work:

```
class NewItemInterestHelper:
    # Removing all class variables

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.__itemsQueue = multiprocessing.Queue()
        self.__itemMutex = multiprocessing.Lock()
        # removing self.__pool since it is just overwritten
        # by the run method

        self.name = name

    # Rest of class follows...
```

Now, since the queue and the lock in the auxiliary process are instead created from a copy of the queue and the lock in the main process. That way they will share enough of their internals to be considered the same queue and lock respectively.

On another note, I assume this to be a simplified example, because as written, there is no need for the mutex/lock at all. There is no need to protect the writing to the queue from the reading from the queue, as that is automatically handled by the underlying system.

Comment: I was reading that calling lock command using the threading import will stop the whole program, not just the thread that is attempting to access the semaphore.  Is this true?  I come from a c++ background trying to jump head first into python